# In dplyr, how to perfrom an action on only certain groups meeting creteria?

Tags: r, dplyr

An example dataframe would be like this:

```
> A
    cell value
1 cell_1     1
2 cell_1     2
3 cell_1     3
4 cell_2     4
5 cell_2     5
6 cell_3     6
7 cell_3     7
8 cell_3     8
9 cell_3     9
```

what I want to achieve is: A %>% group_by(cell), then if there are fewer than 3 rows in a group, the "value" column of rows in that group will be set to "notAvailable".

The final effect would be something like this:

```
> A
    cell value
1 cell_1     1
2 cell_1     2
3 cell_1     3
4 cell_2     notAvailable
5 cell_2     notAvailable
6 cell_3     6
7 cell_3     7
8 cell_3     8
9 cell_3     9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(cell) %>%
  mutate(value = if(n() < 3) 'notAvailable' else as.character(value))

# cell   value       
#  <chr>  <chr>       
#1 cell_1 1           
#2 cell_1 2           
#3 cell_1 3           
#4 cell_2 notAvailable
#5 cell_2 notAvailable
#6 cell_3 6           
#7 cell_3 7           
#8 cell_3 8           
#9 cell_3 9
```

Perhaps, better to use `NA` than `'notAvailable'` since using `'notAvailable'` turns the column to characters.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(cell = c("cell_1", "cell_1", "cell_1", "cell_2", 
"cell_2", "cell_3", "cell_3", "cell_3", "cell_3"), value = 1:9), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: @xwhitelight What do you mean? It works fine for me as shown for the data shared.

Comment: It gives errors on my try. I don't think if_else is supposed to work that way and 'notAvailable' must be repeated to a vector.

Comment: I am not using `if_else`. I am using `if` which is used for scalar inputs. Did you copy paste my code as it is?

Comment: It worked for me! One small question though: is it possible to keep just one row for cell_2?

Comment: Yes, you can add `%>% slice(if(n() < 3) 1L else 1:n())` in the next line.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(cell) %>%
  mutate(
    value = ifelse(n()<3, rep("notAvailable", n()), as.character(value))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.